# URL manipulation for weather rest api

Tags: kotlin, geolocation, retrofit, rest, weather-api

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to change the city, based on the current location.Is there a way I can manipulate "{city}"? This is probably a really easy question. As of current, my app is aware of device location but I don't know how to manipulate the url. Should I use a different api?

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("weather/{city}")
    suspend fun getWeather():Response<Weather> 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@Path](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html) for this.

For example:

```
@GET("weather/{city}")
suspend fun getWeather(@Path("city") val city: String):Response<Weather>
```

Now, when you call the function. Pass the string to dynamically update "city".